# Primitive savannah man taken into a tower city and made sophisticated

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story about 30 years ago about a hunter-gatherer man living on an African-type plain or Savannah where these strange tower structures rose into the clouds. He went to sleep beside one and was taken in and attempted to be civilized by the inhabitants. He got somewhat sophisticated but pined for his previous existence so much he eventually threw himself from the tower city to his death on his true home far below.

Comment: It doesn't sound like an exact match, so I won't post it as an answer, but [Brave New World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_New_World) has some parallels.

Comment: Ditto my vote for Brave New World.

Comment: No, it's not BNW. What I'm asking about was a short story, novella at best. In any case, I'm very familiar with that tale and that ain't it. Cheers for the input.

Comment: @Aaron I figured it wasn't what you're looking for, which is why I didn't post an answer, but I left the comment in case someone who *was* looking for BNW saw your title and thought it might be a match.  BTW, I hope you get the right answer... sounds like an interesting story!